# Can getStaticPaths return a string when you map over it?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I want to get a single user so i'm trying to find by username instead of by Id but i keep getting this, **Error: required parameter (username) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /users/[username]**

```
[username].tsx

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:7000/api/users')
  const data = await res.json()

//Here is where the issue is, in Params can i get the username instead of the Id?
  const paths = data.map((path: any) => {
    return {
      params: {
        username: path?.username?.toString(),
      }
    }
  })
  return { 
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}

//Here is the route from my backend to get a single user

export const getStaticProps = async (context: any) => {
    const username = context.params.username;
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:7000/api/users/get-user/' + username);
  const data = await res.json();
  // console.log(context, "context");
  
  return {
    props: {
      user: data
    },
  }
}
```

I should also mention that I'm not quite sure if my Linking to this route is correct to begin with, i have something like: Link **href={'/users/' + props.tweet?.username}** className='userName' > {props.tweet?.username}

Can i also get a brief but thorough explanation on how linking a text to a single route like([slug].js) itself specifically works?
I used 'users' in the <Link href={'/users/'> here because the pages component is inside of a **users** folder, But i'm not even sure if that's the right way or if it's correct.